# Parsing with cURL

Tags: php, parsing, curl

Have a problem with parsing a certain part of the page i need. Found a code which helps to solve the task (parsing the page entirely), tried to modernize it but without any result(

```
function get_web_page( $url )
{
        $uagent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0";

        $ch = curl_init( $url );

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);   // возвращает веб-страницу
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);           // не возвращает заголовки
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);   // переходит по редиректам
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");        // обрабатывает все кодировки
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $uagent);  // useragent
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 120); // таймаут соединения
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);        // таймаут ответа
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 50);       // останавливаться после 10-ого редиректа
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]."/my_cookies.txt");  
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]."/my_cookies.txt");

        $content = curl_exec( $ch );
        curl_close( $ch );
        return $content;
}

$response=get_web_page('http://group.aliexpress.com/ruNew.htm?spm=2114.11020108.300.1.PDAme1&tracelog=rugroupbuyyt01');
echo $response;
```

How to remove unwanted parts of the page? For example I need only one block with class "group-product-list".

Thank you!

Comment: You need HTML DOM parser, e.g. PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/). It will allow you to select specific of HTML and retrieve it. 
For example :

```
// Create DOM from URL or file
$html =file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');

// Find all images 
foreach($html->find('img') as $element) 
       echo $element->src . '<br>';

// Find all links 
foreach($html->find('a') as $element) 
       echo $element->href . '<br>';
```

Documentation: [Manual](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm)

Comment: thank you, and what about css? Should i make it myself?

Comment: You can add classes to your tags or use id's. Just to make them selectable via CSS selectors.  For more information, see http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp